# Codeigniter: Is there a way to identify the view that initiated a request within the controller class?

Tags: class, codeigniter, redirect, view

I have a certain class which receives request from different views. It handles the request and should redirect the user to the view that they were "visiting". Is there any way I can identify this view so i can load it back to the browser?

Thank you.

Comment: How does your view send requests? Views are generally used to display html/get variables passed to them. Perhaps.. javascript - history.go(-1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just redirect back the referring page?  Here are some functions I usually put in a MY_url_helper.php file to accomplish this:

```
<?php
function redirect_back()
{
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}

function save_next($next_url = NULL)
{
    if (empty($next_url))
    {
        $next_url = current_url();
    }

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->session->set_userdata('next_url', $next_url);
}

function redirect_next($fallback = '')
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $next = $CI->session->userdata('next_url');
    if ( !empty($next))
    {
        $CI->session->unset_userdata('next_url');
        redirect($next);
    }

    redirect($fallback);
}
```

Couple ways to use these functions:

1. Call `redirect_back()` in the controller action that processes, say, form data
2. Call `save_next()` in the controller action that displays the view, then call `redirect_next()` in the controller action that processes the form data

It's not all too RESTlike, but it gets the job done, freeing you to focus on the more important things in life...

Comment: Thank you! Redirect_back() is exactly what I need.